# onclick event in actionlink not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try :

@Html.ActionLink("Next", "ADDNewAdvertisment", "AdvDetails", new { onclick = "validtion();" }, null)

and I try :

@Html.ActionLink("Next", "ADDNewAdvertisment", "AdvDetails", new { @onclick = "validtion();" }, null)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Id to call onclick function

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "ADDNewAdvertisment", "AdvDetails", new { onclick = "validtion();" }, null)
```

instead of this you can use it like this -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "ADDNewAdvertisment", "AdvDetails", new { id="onclickBtn" }, null)
```

write javascript function

```
$('#onclickBtn').click(function(){
  //do something
});
```